# Robocopy returns Success despite not finding Destination

Tags: robocopy

We have an application that handles data transfer to a cloud and to a local server location.
We use Robocopy for the local transfer as such:

`ROBOCOPY.EXE  "%SRC%" "%DEST%" /S /V /FP /IS /Z /R:5 /W:5 /ETA /LOG+:%NETDRIVE%\log\robolog.txt"

Our app monitors the robocopy output. If transfers fail or do not complete they are repeated.

We did a test, where the network was pysically disconnected during the transfer with following output.

```
Robocopy Header as expected
-----
                           1    SOURCE_DIR.    // The 1 indicate there is one file in the source dir

ERROR 53 (0x00000035) Accessing Destination Directory DEST_DIR
The network path was not found.              // This repeats five times as expected with the option /R:5

ERROR: RETRY LIMIT EXCEEDED.


               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
   Files :         0         0         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :         0         0         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:27   0:00:00             0:00:25   0:00:02   
   Ended : DATE
```

The return code is 0. " No errors occurred, and no copying was done.
The source and destination directory trees are completely synchronized."
[Ref for return codes](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html)

This makes no sense to me and I cannot reproduce it in any way.

1. If `SOURCE_DIR` is empty, the first line after the header indicates 0
2. IF `DEST_DIR` cannot be reached and throws an error, 0 should not be the return code.
3. Since there must be a file in `SOURCE_DIR` (indicated by the 1), not all columns in the `FILES` row of the summary should be 0. THe file should "be" somewhere.
4. `ERROR 53` (`DEST` not reachable) `RETRY LIMIT EXCEEDED` are errors. After errors there is no summary.

2 Questions:

1. What constellation can result in this incoherent output and return code.
2. If returning 0 is possible when network not is not reachable, how do you get robocopy to report its failure correctly.

Or am I am completely on the wrong track here?